# Firebase FCM bulk personalized push

Tags: php, firebase, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

is it possible to send a bulk of pushes but each message is personalized, for example with a name, the goal is to only make one request to the API and not 1 request per user

Is it possible ? and if yes, how can I do it ?
I am using pure cURL (php) so code using the library will not be helpful..
Also I am using the old FCM API..
(https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. There is no mail-merge like functionality for Firebase Cloud Messaging. You will have to send each message separately.